# Getting the values from multiple chekboxes in an HTML form in php

Tags: php, html

I have such a code. It is an HTML form:

```
echo '<b>GPA: </b>'.$yaz["GPA"].'<br>'.'<b>ALES Verbal Score:     
</b>'.$yaz["ALES_VERBAL_SCORES"].'<br>'.'<b>Ales Math Score:     
</b>'.$yaz["ALES_MATH_SCORE"].'<br>'.'<b>ALES Equal Weight Score:     
</b>'.$yaz["ALES_EQUALWEIGHT_SCORES"].'<br>'.'<b>TOEFL PBT:     
</b>'.$yaz["TOEFL_PBT"].'<br>'.'<b>TOEFL CBT:     
</b>'.$yaz["TOEFL_CBT"].'<br>'.'<b>TOEFL     
IBT:    
</b>'.$yaz["TOEFL_IBT"].'<br>'.'<b>IELTS: </b>'.$yaz["IELTS"].'<br>'.'
<br><input type="checkbox" value="'.$yaz["NAME"].'" name="check_'.$counter.'" />'.'
<div class="clear"></div></div>';
```

As you notice, there is a checkbox input at the end of the "echo" code. I want to get the value of checkbox for each loop and list them. How can I manage it?
Thanks...

Comment: where is the loop as you said in the a question ?

Comment: as you see, there is name="check_'.$counter.'" in the input type of chekbox. And the counter automatically increases in each turn.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using this

```
'<input type="checkbox" value="'.$yaz["NAME"].'" name="check_'.$counter.'" />'
```

you can just use

```
<input type="checkbox" value="'.$yaz["NAME"].'" name="check[]" />'
```

while you submit the form you can access it  as

```
$_POST['check']
```

and it ll come as an array in order